# Hibernate logging in log files?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, log4j

I read something on stackoverflow and some tutorials, but i still don't solve this problem. Hibernate does not logging in log files, only in  console.

Here is pieces of code (This is not full code):

DAO:

```
@PersistenceContext(unitName = "entityManagerFactoryBPM")
private EntityManager em;

@Override
public SomeEntity someMethod(BigDecimal Id){
    Query query = em.createNativeQuery("SOME QUERY", SomeEntity.class);
    query.setParameter("id", id);
    return (SomeEntity)query.getSingleResult();
}
```

JPAConfig (I set there HIBERNATE_SHOW_SQL_VALUE = "true";):

```
public class JPAConfig {

  private final String HIBERNATE_DIALECT_KEY = "dialect.key=hibernate.dialect";
  private String HIBERNATE_DIALECT_VALUE = "org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle12gDialect";
  private String HIBERNATE_SHOW_SQL_KEY = "hibernate.show_sql";
  private String HIBERNATE_SHOW_SQL_VALUE = "true";
  private String HIBERNATE_PACKAGES_TO_SCAN = "com.bla.package12";


@Bean
public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactoryBPM() {
  LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactoryBean = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
  entityManagerFactoryBean.setDataSource(dataSourceBPM);
  entityManagerFactoryBean.setPersistenceProviderClass(HibernatePersistenceProvider.class);
  entityManagerFactoryBean.setPackagesToScan(HIBERNATE_PACKAGES_TO_SCAN);
  entityManagerFactoryBean.setJpaProperties(hibProperties());
  return entityManagerFactoryBean;
}


private Properties hibProperties() {
  Properties properties = new Properties();
  properties.put(HIBERNATE_DIALECT_KEY,    HIBERNATE_DIALECT_VALUE);
  properties.put(HIBERNATE_SHOW_SQL_KEY, HIBERNATE_SHOW_SQL_VALUE);
    return properties;
}
```

I add this in Appender:

```
<logger name="org.hibernate" additivity="false" level="DEBUG">
   <appender-ref ref="DAO_LAYER_LOG" />
</logger>
<logger name="org.hibernate.type" additivity="false" level="TRACE">
   <appender-ref  ref="DAO_LAYER_LOG"/>
</logger>
```

What else i need to do to get logging in log files? I also got some xml for log4j. Other logs works fine, only hibernate does not.

Comment: looks like that you are initializing log4 with a diferent xml path than defautl after persistence, so when persistence created their logs, used defaults levels, are you using log4j or slfj4? are you using springboot or a context listener to start it?

Comment: If you're using Spring, don't reinvent JPA; use Hibernate's JPA support and use Spring Data JPA. The entire JPA configuration you posted can be eliminated with Spring Boot, and you can just write `SomeEntity findByLmId(BigDecimal lmId);` on a Spring Data interface and you're finished.

Comment: Hibernate is using SLF4J. See also https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/core.old/reference/en/html/configuration-logging.html